# How to save the progress of a ProgressBar using SharedPreferences in Android Studio - Java?

Tags: java, android-studio

I've been experimenting for a couple of hours now on how to save the progress of a progressBar even if I closed/destroyed the app. I tried using the same method in TextViews and it works just fine. So, I'm wondering where I went wrong. Below is my code that I've done and any response is greatly appreciated! Have a nice day!

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static final String PROGRESS = "progress";
    private int CurrentProgress;
    private ProgressBar progressBar;
    private Button addProgress;
    
    public static final String SHARED_PREFS="sharedPrefs";
    private int getCurrentProgress;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        addProgress = findViewById(R.id.addProgress);

        progressBar.setMax(1000);


        addProgress.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                    CurrentProgress = CurrentProgress + 100;
                     progressBar.setProgress(CurrentProgress);

                     saveData();
                 }
                });
                loadData();
                updateData();
    }

    public void saveData(){

        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFS, MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

        editor.putInt(PROGRESS, CurrentProgress);

        editor.apply();
    }
    public void loadData() {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFS, MODE_PRIVATE);

        getCurrentProgress = sharedPreferences.getInt(PROGRESS, CurrentProgress);
    }

    public void updateData() {

        progressBar.setProgress(CurrentProgress);


    }
}
```

Comment: refer to [android activity life cycle docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle) , so that you know how to save the progress of a progressBar even if you closed destroyed the app

Comment: @abdoSalm I know about that, i knew how to save the text even if i destroyed the app but when i tried it on a progressbar it didn't work

Comment: store `progressBar.getProgress();` into any variable and save it to `SharedPreferences`.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems with your logic and syntax. Logic first:

First, when you're setting the value of `getCurrentProgress` in the `loadData` method, the second argument of `.getInt` is the *default value* that you want to set `getCurrentProgress` to. Right now, you're saying that if `PROGRESS` is not found in sharedPrefs, then the `getCurrentProgress` will be set to `CurrentProgress`, which is empty. Just change it to whatever you want the default value to be, probably zero or one:

`getCurrentProgress = sharedPreferences.getInt(PROGRESS, 0);`

Second, in your `updateData` method, you're setting `progressBar`'s progress to `CurrentProgress`, which is, again, empty. You should be setting it to `getCurrentProgress`.

For syntax: your choice of variable names is very confusing. You should not name an `int` `getCurrentProgress`, that is the name of a method. You should not capitalize a variable name, `CurrentProgress` looks like a class. Also, make sure your indentations line up properly - the calls to `loadData` and `updateData` in `onCreate` are indented too far and it is difficult to read.

Also, I recommend adding more descriptive names to your variables, eg `addProgress` might be better as `addProgressBtn`. This helps you keep track of things better once you have a more complicated layout.

Here is what the code should look like:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static final String PROGRESS = "progress";
    private int currentProgress;
    private ProgressBar progressBar;
    private Button addProgressBtn;
    
    public static final String SHARED_PREFS="sharedPrefs";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        addProgressBtn = findViewById(R.id.addProgress);

        progressBar.setMax(1000);


        addProgressBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                currentProgress = currentProgress + 100; // currentProgress += 100 works too
                progressBar.setProgress(currentProgress);

                saveData();
            }
        });

        loadData();
        updateData();
    }

    public void saveData(){

        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFS, MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

        editor.putInt(PROGRESS, currentProgress);

        editor.apply();
    }
    public void loadData() {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFS, MODE_PRIVATE);

        currentProgress = sharedPreferences.getInt(PROGRESS, 0);
    }

    public void updateData() {

        progressBar.setProgress(currentProgress);


    }
}
```